# Como calcular as dimensões de um elemento SVG

Tags: javascript, html, svg

Como calcular as dimensões de um elemento `svg` de maneira consistente entre browsers? Na verdade o único a não responder de forma consistente é o Firefox.

Seria interessante perceber a razão das disparidades do `getBoundingClientRect` em browsers diferentes também.

Tentei comparar os resultados usando `getBoundingClientRect` e `getComputedStyle`. O `getComputedStyle` é consistente mas não existe no IE8.

```
var svg = document.querySelector('svg');
var gBCR = svg.getBoundingClientRect().width;
var bBox = svg.getBBox().width;
var gCS = window.getComputedStyle(svg, null).width;
console.log('gBCR: ' + Math.round(gBCR) + ' - gCS: ' + gCS + ' - bBox: ' + Math.round(bBox));

// Resultados:
// Firefox: gBCR: 142 - gCS: 400px - bBox: 363
// Chrome:  gBCR: 400 - gCS: 400px - bBox: 363
```

#### http://jsfiddle.net/23x8S/

HTML:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 512 512" height="200px">
    <title>HTML5 Logo</title>
    <polygon fill="#E44D26" points="107.644,470.877 74.633,100.62 437.367,100.62 404.321,470.819 255.778,512" />
    <polygon fill="#F16529" points="256,480.523 376.03,447.246 404.27,130.894 256,130.894             " />
    <polygon fill="#EBEBEB" points="256,268.217 195.91,268.217 191.76,221.716 256,221.716 256,176.305 255.843,176.305 142.132,176.305 143.219,188.488 154.38,313.627 256,313.627" />
    <polygon fill="#EBEBEB" points="256,386.153 255.801,386.206 205.227,372.55 201.994,336.333 177.419,336.333 156.409,336.333 162.771,407.634 255.791,433.457 256,433.399" />
    <path d="M108.382,0h23.077v22.8h21.11V0h23.078v69.044H152.57v-23.12h-21.11v23.12h-23.077V0z" />
    <path d="M205.994,22.896h-20.316V0h63.72v22.896h-20.325v46.148h-23.078V22.896z" />
    <path d="M259.511,0h24.063l14.802,24.26L313.163,0h24.072v69.044h-22.982V34.822l-15.877,24.549h-0.397l-15.888-24.549v34.222h-22.58V0z" />
    <path d="M348.72,0h23.084v46.222h32.453v22.822H348.72V0z" />
    <polygon fill="#FFFFFF" points="255.843,268.217 255.843,313.627 311.761,313.627 306.49,372.521 255.843,386.191 255.843,433.435 348.937,407.634 349.62,399.962 360.291,280.411 361.399,268.217 349.162,268.217" />
    <polygon fill="#FFFFFF" points="255.843,176.305 255.843,204.509 255.843,221.605 255.843,221.716 365.385,221.716 365.385,221.716 365.531,221.716 366.442,211.509 368.511,188.488 369.597,176.305" />
<svg>
```

Cross-post no SO: https://stackoverflow.com/q/23731026/2256325

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A solução mais consistente parece ser `.getComputedStyle`. E uma vez que o IE8 não suporta elementos svg, nem o `.getComputedStyle` então no caso do IE8 e anteriores "Problema sem solução resolvido está`.

Assim, conforme coloquei já na pergunta hoje de manhã o getComputedStyle dá o mesmo valor entre FF e Chrome. Criei então uma função para ter em conta margem e padding:

The solution I found for this was to use `.getComputedStyle()`. And since svg elements are not supported in old IE8- browsers, computed style is the way to give consistent results.

So I ended up making in my library:

```
function svgSize(el) {
    var gCS = window.getComputedStyle(this),
        bounds;
    var gCScomponents = {
        height: ['height', 'paddingTop', 'paddingBottom', 'borderTopWidth', 'borderBottomWidth'],
        width: ['width', 'paddingLeft', 'paddingRight', 'borderLeftWidth', 'borderRightWidth']
    };
    bounds = {
        x: 0,
        y: 0
    };
    gCScomponents.height.each(function (css) {
        bounds.y += computeSize(gCS[css]);
    });
    gCScomponents.width.each(function (css) {
        bounds.x += computeSize(gCS[css]);
    });
    return bounds;
}

// Resultados:
// Firefox: gBCR: 142 - gCS: 400px - bBox: 363
// Chrome:  gBCR: 400 - gCS: 400px - bBox: 363
```

**MDN - [documentação](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/window.getComputedStyle)**